# Count per year with only start and end year data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a line chart in `ggplot2` with 350 beer breweries. I want to count per year how many active breweries there are. I only have the start and end date of brewery activity. `tidyverse` answers prefered.

`begin_datum_jaar` is year the brewery started. `eind_datum_jaar` is in which year the brewery has ended.

example data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  brouwerijnaam begin_datum_jaar eind_datum_jaar
  <chr>                    <int>           <int>
1 Brand                     1340            2019
2 Heineken                  1592            2019
3 Grolsche                  1615            2019
4 Bavaria                   1719            2010
```

dput:

```
df <- structure(list(brouwerijnaam = c("Brand", "Heineken", "Grolsche", 
"Bavaria"), begin_datum_jaar = c(1340L, 1592L, 1615L, 1719L), 
    eind_datum_jaar = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2010L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Desired output where `etc.` is a placeholder.

```
# A tibble: 13 x 2
   year      n
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 1340      1
 2 1341      1
 3 1342      1
 4 1343      1
 5 etc.      1
 6 1592      2
 7 1593      2
 8 etc.      2
 9 1625      3
10 1626      3
11 1627      3
12 1628      3
13 etc.      3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `map2` to get the sequence from start to end date for each corresponding element, `unnest` the `list` column to expand and use `count` to get the frequency of the 'year'

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   transmute(year = map2(begin_datum_jaar, eind_datum_jaar, `:`)) %>%
   unnest %>%
   count(year)
# A tibble: 680 x 2
#    year     n
#   <int> <int>
# 1  1340     1
# 2  1341     1
# 3  1342     1
# 4  1343     1
# 5  1344     1
# 6  1345     1
# 7  1346     1
# 8  1347     1
# 9  1348     1
#10  1349     1
# … with 670 more rows
```

---

Or using `Map` from `base R`

```
table(unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = `:`, df[-1]))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Could try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  do(data.frame(brouwerij = .$brouwerijnaam,
                Year = seq(.$begin_datum_jaar, .$eind_datum_jaar, by = 1))) %>%
  count(Year, name = "Active breweries") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = `Active breweries`)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal()
```

Or try `expand` for the first part:

```
df %>%
  group_by(brouwerijnaam) %>%
  expand(Year = begin_datum_jaar:eind_datum_jaar) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(Year, name = "Active breweries")
```

However, note that the `rowwise`, `do` or `expand` parts are resource intensive and may take long time. If that happens, I'd rather use `data.table` for expanding the data frame, and then continue, like below:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

df <- setDT(df)[, .(Year = seq(begin_datum_jaar, eind_datum_jaar, by = 1)), by = brouwerijnaam]

df %>%
  count(Year, name = "Active breweries") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = `Active breweries`)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal()
```

The above gives you the plot directly. If you'd like to save it to a data frame first (and then do the `ggplot2` thing), this is the main part (I use the `data.table` for expanding as it's much faster in my experience):

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

df <- setDT(df)[
  , .(Year = seq(begin_datum_jaar, eind_datum_jaar, by = 1)), 
  by = brouwerijnaam] %>%
  count(Year, name = "Active breweries")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 680 x 2
    Year `Active breweries`
   <dbl>              <int>
 1  1340                  1
 2  1341                  1
 3  1342                  1
 4  1343                  1
 5  1344                  1
 6  1345                  1
 7  1346                  1
 8  1347                  1
 9  1348                  1
10  1349                  1
# ... with 670 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  df1 <- data.frame(year=1000:2020) # Enter range for years of choice

  df1 %>% 
  rowwise()%>% 
  mutate(cnt=nrow(df %>% 
                    filter(begin_datum_jaar<year & eind_datum_jaar>year) 
                  )
         )
```